# How to connect two HP 1910-48G switches

Tags: networking, switch, hp, network-topology

My company have two [HP 1910-48G Switches](http://www8.hp.com/emea_africa/en/products/networking-switches/product-detail.html?oid=4177649). One of them is on my flat and the other one is two flat above. I'm not a network guy but my manager wants me to connect these switches and he doesn't want to limit himself for 1Gbps. What is the best way for connect two of them?

I read [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/308545/how-to-connect-multiple-switches-together) and learn a way called "trunking, port aggregation" but is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I know reality stinks, but reality does not care. THe switch has a maximum of 1gbit per port so that is the limit. Point.

What you can do is theoretically use muliple links in a link aggregate group to get more bandwidth. Sadly it does not look like that particular switch supports it.

Pretty sure reality does not care about what your manager wants.

Port aggregation is the only way to do that - short of getting switches with support 10g. Which basically means - running muptiple cables (and using multiple ports). I do the same here in my offices (server room to house distribution is running 2gbit) and it works fine.

Comment: the user guide has a chapter called "static/dynamic link aggregation" are you sure that they does not support it?

Comment: No. I went to the linked site and there is nothing there indicating they do support it. THat simple. THey list a lot of protocols and features, but link aggregation is not there. Check the manual - maybe it is, maybe the manual is a standard manual for a set of switches and those particular ones do not support this feature.

Comment: Just made another check - tehy do. you seem to be able to aggregate two ports. Just follow the manual. That will give you 2gbit per side (2 send, 2 receive).

Comment: ok, could you edit your message because i mark it as an answer.

Comment: Done. Have fun with it - we do the same (2gbit house to server room) and it works fine.

Comment: last question can we use Gigabit SFP ports for team aggregation?

Comment: No idea - read the documentation. THis is switch dependent. I dont use those.... but technically there is no reason why this should not be possible.

Comment: @Ogun It would be really strange for that kind of switch not supporting link aggregation. Even if they forgot to note It in specs. This guys was lucky for sure ;):  http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Web-and-Unmanaged/1910-48G-JE009A-LACP-Link-Aggregation/td-p/5931479#.UqGvneXh6YA

Comment: @Veniamin thanks. I configured the switch and tested for 2gbps and it worked. it was really easy :) when you don't know how to do it, it looks like very hard to achive :)

Comment: Yeah. Same here - when I set up my first LACP i was quite - afraid. But once you find the proper items in the documentation, that really is just a "it works" thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could aggregate even more than two port. This switch also support 802.3ad LACP for load balance. I'm using it with openvswitch's bonding, 5 links, works fine for me.
And also it has some "stacking" feature...